# Difference between building a website with and without CMS

Tags: content-management-system, aem

I have started to learn about Content Management Systems(Adobe Experience Manager) and I'm not able to find something good to explain the transition from, how you would normally build a website, to using a CMS. Here is what I know:
We have the website code(HTML files, other files, assets etc.). We have a database server which our code will interact with. We have a web server which will serve our site. Of course there will typically be 3 servers in case we use MEAN or MERN or some other stack, the frontend server, the node server and the database server. But still the overall process is the same, the website code is stored somewhere(this code is interacting with a DB server) and a web server is serving the website.

How does all this happen when we use a CMS?

All I can understand right now is that CMS can be used to generate website without having to code it. How will the generated website be served? Will the CMS provide me let's say a folder having all the code and I still need a web server to serve this code? What if I'm working in a team? Does it work like a hosted git repository where let's say we don't have a connection, we can still work on our changes and then publish them later. In this case the CMS will store our website on cloud? In short what are steps from starting to build a website using a CMS to any user actually seeing it.

Answer (score 1):

Technically, the way CMS build the website is fairly the same as how you build the website on your own. However, the server infrastructure setup may be vary among different providers.

For editing the code, I suggest you to contact the provider or read the documentation. The limitation of accessing code should be depending on providers. Btw, this would be a business secret and providers may refuse to provide the code folder.

The difference between with and without CMS might be:
CMS providers simplify most of the steps of creating a website from scratch. By providing a graphical user interface, you can customize your (going to build) website. As a result, you can skip the difficulties of writing codes.

If you want to build a website using CMS, just visit a CMS provider website and follow their tutorials to do so. Some common CMS providers include Wordpress or Web-flow. If you are want to build e-commerce website, I will suggest Shopify. Of course, it's just example, you may try any CMS provider as you wish.

Usually, after you sign up an account in the CMS provider, you can start configuring your (going to build) website. Once, you finish your setup, you can launch your website. Users and you can search the website on browsers. Btw, you might need to pay before using the service (it depends).

I hope this can issue your enquiry.

Answer (score 0):

If you opt for a CMS, you'll be able to move hosts, change domain names, and make other changes to your site at will. The CMS is ready to integrate with whatever systems you want to use. Creators who want full control over their websites should go with a content management system over a website builder.